# What does this sum converge to (binomial theorem)

Tags: limits, summation

Let $t, a \in \left(0,1\right)$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$.
$$
\mbox{What is the limit of}\quad
s = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{an + b}
{n\choose k}t^{n - k}\,\,\left(\,{1 - t}\,\right)^{k}
\quad {\large ?}.
$$
We can assume that $s$ exists because $s \leq 1$ and this series is monotonic. I already know that
$$
s =
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & a \geq t
\\
1 & \, a < t
\end{array}
\right.
$$
because that would solve the actual exercise perfectly.

Thanks for reading and for the help.

Comment: What is $x$...?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it

Comment: The limit calculation should follow from the law of large numbers although you might be able to do it with Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu, that was a really good tip!